# To start a jenkins job within another jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

My requirement is to build an envelope jenkins job which will internally initiate another jenkins pipeline based on the parameter. Say I have 10 jenkins job, they all should be wrapped into a single parent job(say 'A). Job is to be triggered remotely from outside network through JWT authentication, the api call should hit the endpoints of the job 'A' then invoke the sub job based on the parameter passed. Can someone please help me how this scenario can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

In a declarative pipeline, you can trigger stages based on chosen parameters (or other conditions) with a [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) block.
And in those stages, you can trigger the builds of other jobs with a [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) step.

```html
pipeline {
  agent any 
  parameters {
     choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: ['dev', "prod"], description: 'You could have other types of parameters besides choice.')
     choice(name: 'ANOTHER_PARAMETER', choices: ['foo', "bar"], description: 'Just an example of another parameter you might want to pass down to child jobs.')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test for dev environment') { // This stage executes only when 'dev' is the chosen parameter. 
      when {
        expression {
          params.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev'
        }
      }
      steps {
        echo "Triggering job b for ${params.ENVIRONMENT} environment."
        build job: 'job-b', wait: false, propagate: false, parameters: [
          string(name: 'ANOTHER_PARAMETER', value: "${params.ANOTHER_PARAMETER}")
        ]
      }
    }

    stage('Test for prod environment') { // This stage executes only when 'prod' is the chosen parameter. 
      when {
        expression {
          params.ENVIRONMENT == 'prod'
        }
      }
      steps {
        echo "Triggering job c for ${params.ENVIRONMENT} environment."
        build job: 'job-c', wait: false, propagate: false, parameters: [
          string(name: 'ANOTHER_PARAMETER', value: "${params.ANOTHER_PARAMETER}")
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we start the job from outside jenkins network?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. The same way you were already doing it? I don't have any experience triggering remotely through JWT. That's a different question. This answer describes the mechanics of triggering further jobs from within your pipeline. However you trigger Job-A, you just need to pass in parameter selections which will then trigger various stages which will in turn trigger additional child jobs.

Comment: I love such short, but complete working examples.